# Creating a vocabulary from a column, after removing stopwords

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a corpus/vocabulary made by all the texts (tokenised) within a column inn my dataframe:

```
User Text
312  Include details about your goal
41   Describe expected and actual results
421  Include any error messages
```

What I would like to do is to remove first the stopwords, then appending all the tokenised word into a list, i.e.:

```
my_list=['Include', 'details', 'goal', 'Describe', 'expected', 'actual', 'results', 'Include', 'error', 'messages']
```

I tried as follows:

```
df['Text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words])
```

but it gives me character, not words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to apply

```
l = df.Text.str.split(' ').sum()
yourlist = [x for x in l if x not in stop_words]
```